# How do I edit all UIButtons with a specific tag in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tags, uibutton

I want to edit all buttons with a specific tag. I have tagged each of the UIButtons  (which I built in IB) from 0-15. I then used the tag button as the index values when searching in my NSMutableArray (investigationsArray). There are 16 items in my array.

I want to implement something like this in my viewWillAppear:

```
if (theButtonTag == 0){

[button setTitle: [[investigationsArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

I would like to simplify my code so eventually I can use a for statement like this:

```
for (buttonTag = 0; buttonTag < [investigationsArray count]; buttonTag ++){

if (theButtonTag == i){    
    [button setTitle: [[investigationsArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

I've looked all over google and can't find anything. Thanks guys.

Comment: Your for loop is going to go outside of your array I believe, because of the "<=". Change it to a "<".

Comment: @XenElement: You're right, I wasn't paying attention. I'll make the edit above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Inspire48 and Alex Nichol I managed to come up with an answer for this. If you try to start at `i = 0`, the code throws an error:`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setTitle:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa180970`. So to make up for this, I just added a blank entry at index0 into my pList, which allows me to start my `for()` statement at `i = 1` instead of `i = 0`.

```
for (int i = 1; i < [investigationsArray count]; i++) {
        UIButton * button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
        NSString * title = [[investigationsArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
        [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

The other change I had to make on the code that both Inspire48 and Alex Nichol used is the following. Instead of using `[self viewWithTag:i]` you need to use `[self.view viewWithTag:i]`.

Thanks again guys!

Comment: Wow! I can't believe you can't set 0.... so illogical. Glad to have found this, and nice catch. More people should know this.

Answer (score 0):

Use a standard `for` loop, as you have up there. `UIView` has a method called [viewWithTag](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/viewWithTag%3a), which will return a view with the tag specified. It's exactly what you want.

**Code snippet:**

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:i];
    [button setTitle: [[investigationsArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"name"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspire48's code above is almost correct, with a small bug.  You want to loop through all of the tags from 0 to 15, and set the title of that button to the value in your array.  Here is some example code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [investigationsArray count]; i++) {
    UIButton * button = (UIButton *)[self viewWithTag:i];
    NSString * title = [[investigationsArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
    [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I would suggest in the end NOT using tags of buttons, but rather having the buttons as keys in an NSDictionary.  You could then have something like:

```
for (UIView * view in [self subviews]) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]) {
        UIButton * button = (UIButton *)view;
        NSString * title = [[investigationsDictionary objectForKey:button] objectForKey:@"name"];
        [button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

You can initialise your dictionary as follows:

```
NSDictionary * investigationsDictionary;
...
investigationsDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:button1, myValue,...,nil];
```

Comment: @Inspire48: Thanks for your help guys. However, when I use the code [self viewWithTag:i] I get the warning "instance method -viewWithTag not found". When I try replacing that with [self.view viewWithTag:i] the warnings go away, but when I try to run the code it crashes with the error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setTitle:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa180970'

Comment: @Matt I'm using Xcode 4.2 Build 4D139. SDK 5 beta 4. Doesn't work on SDK 4 either. Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out. If you try to use that code with tag=0 it throws the exception. So I went into my plist, added a blank item at index 0 and ran the code with i starting at 1 instead of 0. I will post a more complete answer in a bit.